Error While Configuring EVM in Substrate Parachain: Conflict in 'syn' Crate
I am trying to configure the EVM for my Substrate parachain and encountered an issue during the process. I am following along with this tutorial.
After implementing this commit as instructed in the tutorial and attempting to compile my node, I receive the following error:

After searching for a solution, I came across this post on Substrate Stack Exchange. However, applying the proposed solution led to a conflict with the syn crate. Here is the error screen:

Environment Details:
OS: macOS Ventura
Version: 13.5.2
Rust Toolchain:
rustup toolchain list
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2021-10-19-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-09-10-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-10-10-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-12-13-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-02-14-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.74-aarch64-apple-darwin
risc0
I forked my parachain repo from this Polkadot parachain template. You can find my forked repo here.
I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this conflict and successfully configure the EVM on my Substrate parachain. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Please copy and paste the log here instead of providing a screenshot.

You will inevitably encounter this issue.
Your polkadot-sdk dependencies are at version https://github.com/sayyedkamran/blockguard-node/commit/69266c74ee67d29ff8337176cd225a47ed230554#diff-6431a3eec6e102bbcffb94387cda89efbe02002649745273fb575234c0018de4R39.
Your frontier dependencies, however, are at version https://github.com/sayyedkamran/blockguard-node/commit/69266c74ee67d29ff8337176cd225a47ed230554#diff-6431a3eec6e102bbcffb94387cda89efbe02002649745273fb575234c0018de4R28, which is three years old.
Even if you resolve this synchronization issue, you will soon face other errors.
The best approach is to find matching versions of the frontier dependencies. Otherwise, consider forking and maintaining your own.
You should use this version https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/tree/polkadot-v1.0.0.

Just keep in mind that all polkadot-sdk dependencies must be on the same version.

Thank you very much for the response. Let me check it.

It resolved my issue. Thank you for the help.
